# Updated DLL is not picked by Web service developed in VB.NET

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, web-services, dll

I have two small projects - c++ (written 10 years old. It is having dsp file. I have upgraded to VS2010 project). Another one is VB.net web service which is calling the C++ DLL

I am trying to hardcode one of the output parameters of the method SearchZip() to see the change in web service by using the modified dll.

**Inside Some.cpp**

```
SearchZip(LPSTR lpstrServer, LPSTR lpstrStreet, LPSTR lpstrMailStop, LPSTR lpstrCity, LPSTR lpstrState, LPSTR lpstrZipCode, LPSTR lpstrCounty, LPSTR lpstrFIPSCounty, LPSTR lpstrRtnString)
```

and add the modified dll to web service. Below is the existing code to import DLL. It is still picking up the old DLL info.

**Inside web service vb file**

```
<DllImport("Some.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SearchZip(ByVal lpstrServer As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrStreet As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrMailStop As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrCity As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrState As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrZipCode As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrCounty As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrFIPSCounty As StringBuilder, _
   ByVal lpstrResult As StringBuilder) As Integer
End Function
```

Web service Project has bin folder. Inside bin folder, there are Some.DLL, Some.PDB and Some.XML. Please let me know how can see the new DLL change.

Comment: Please help. Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try stopping and restarting the web service.
2. Make sure there is not an older copy of the DLL anywhere on the drive. If there is, it's possible that is the one being used.
3. Make sure you are really replacing the DLL with the newer version.

Comment: Probably not necessary, but he might want to check the GAC.